# Can't move files based on file name with any extension

Tags: python

I have created this program, and everything works until I try to specify moving the files based on the name. I can transfer the files individually if I include the file extension. However, I'd like to move the file no matter the extension and nothing I've done will fix it. I am relatively new to programming only taken one semester class on python so some of this is still new to me.

```
  # list of extensions
  #extensions_dir = {".jpg", ".pdf", ".docx", ".txt", ".xlsx", 
  #".gif", ".png"}
  
  # lists the files in folder
  files = os.listdir(downloads)

 #splits up extenstions
 extensions = {files.split('.') [-1] for files in files if 
 os.path.isfile(os.path.join(downloads, files))}

 #combines all the file extensions in the list
 all_extensions = [extensions.split('.') for extensions in files]

 for file in files:
    if file == "4410." + str(all_extensions):
      shutil.move(os.path.join(downloads, file), 
      control_systems)
    if file == "4470.txt":
      shutil.move(os.path.join(downloads, file), signal_processing)
    if file == "4451":
      shutil.move(os.path.join(downloads, file), embedded)
    if file == "3320":
      shutil.move(os.path.join(downloads, file), electronics)
```

I have tried the using the str(all_extensions) but have not been able to implement that.

Comment: Please post code here, as text, not images. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly, 
which text allows for (and pictures do not).
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience, it is my first time posting, I have edited the code to make it text.